# Removing Data on Maps with different view controllers

Tags: swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, annotations, modal-dialog

I am really struggling on an issue that I think is rather interesting and quite difficult. My application lets the user create annotation locations within a Mapview. They also have the option to edit and delete these locations in another modal view controller.

The issue I am facing is that when the user presses delete, which removes the location from firebase, the annotation is still displayed upon the map. I cannot reload my annotation data within the view did appear as this does not suit my application. I cant have my annotations being reloaded every time I bring up the Mapview.

I need to figure out a way to implement an annotation reload when the delete button is pressed. However, as this happens within my delete view controller (which does not contain the mapView) I cannot use the reload function. Is there a way to connect view controllers so that I can apply the reload function when delete is pressed?

Updated Code **

This is my map view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate, DeleteVCDelegate {
let EditSaveSpotController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditVC") as! EditSaveSpotViewController

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    EditSaveSpotController.delegate = self

}


func wholeRefresh() {

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid

    let userLocationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users/\(uid)/personalLocations")

    userLocationsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in


        for item in snapshot.children {
            guard let snapshot = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }

            let newSkatepark = Skatepark(snapshot: snapshot)

            self.skateparks.append(newSkatepark)

            self.addAnnotation(park: newSkatepark)


        }
    })

    if let annotations = mapView.annotations {

        mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)

    }

    for item in skateparks {

        self.addAnnotation(park: item)

    }



}
```

This is my delete view controller:

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

 protocol DeleteVCDelegate {
 func wholeRefresh()
 }

 class EditSaveSpotViewController: UIViewController  {
 var delegate: DeleteVCDelegate?


  @IBAction func deleteSkateSpot(_ sender: Any) {




    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).child("personalLocations/\(parkId!)")

    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in



        self.ref.setValue(nil)

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.delegate?.wholeRefresh()

     //   self.delegate?.mainRefresh()

        print("CheckWorking")


    })



}
```

}

Comment: You could use a simple delegate/protocol for your modal delete view and make your` mapview` implement it then you can use that to call your annotation reload

Comment: That sounds perfect, however I am unsure how to correctly implement a delegate protocol. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: simple example can be found here:  http://stephenradford.me/creating-a-delegate-in-swift/

Comment: I managed to create the protocol, however it never actually function when the delete button is pressed?

Comment: you need to update your code to show how you implemented your protocol and how you are calling it

Comment: Hard to tell what is what with your code. I will see if I can post an example.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate that

Comment: where is the code used to present the delete view controller? Also you are dismissing your view before calling the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

This is very high level and I did not have a chance to verify but it should be enough to get you going:

Modal Delete View

```
protocol DeleteVCDelegate {
    func mainRefresh()
}

class DeleteVC: UIViewController {
    var delegate: DeleteVCDelegate?

    //your delete code
    @IBAction func deleteSkateSpot(_ sender: Any) {
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).child("personalLocations/\(parkId!)")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.ref.setValue(nil)

            //call to delegate
            self.delegate?.mainRefresh()
        })
    }
}
```

MapView Class (implement DeleteVCDelegate)

```
class mapVC: MKMapViewDelegate, DeleteVCDelegate{

    //when you present your DeleteVC set its delegate to the map view
    let vc=(self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "deleteVC"))! as! DeleteVC

    //set the delegate
    vc.delegate=self

    //present deleteVC
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)

    //implement delegate method of DeleteVC
    func mainRefresh(){
        //dismiss modal
        self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
            //update view
            self.loadLocations()
            self.annotationRefresh()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This slightly confused me more, obviously its very difficult to discuss over stack overflow and I appreciate it. I will try work around this and figure it out

Comment: Are you creating completely separate classes for the functions?

Comment: just two classes, one for your mapview and one for your modal view that you said contains the delete button. The map view can be a UIVIewController or whatever you have it set to be.

Comment: So I am creating new classes within my view controllers? Not using the current ones?

Comment: My assumption is that you have two view controllers, each are custom classes that you created.

Comment: Yes, I have two view controllers with classes. However, they are just the standard classes you would create such as a ViewController class for the Map. An EditViewController class for the delete. But it now sounds like i need to create another class within each of these controllers?

Comment: No, you would put this in the two classes you have. I don't know that names of your classes so I just used generic names. The DeleteVC should be what is in your EditViewController class for the delete and the MapVC code should go in your ViewConroller with the map.

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried, unfortunately it didn't work. It may be because I am not segueing within my delete button. I just have a cancel button. Would this make a difference if I segue from the delete button?

Comment: it doesn't matter as long as you assign the delegate before you transition or present the delete view. In my example, you can see how I present it by referencing it via storyboard but you could use a segue and then assign the delegate to the destination view in the prepareForSegue

Comment: Okay thank you, I must have not been assigning the delegate on the first map view controller properly

Comment: I seem to have implemented everything perfectly. However, its not working. I have printed the delegate and it prints "nil"? Do you know why this would be happening

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to without seeing your updated code. show your complete implementation of your two classes.

Comment: I have updated my code from the two different view controllers